# how to add values to the end of an attribute of an element? - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I know there are other ways to workaround this but this just popped in my head and I couldn't find the answer.

I have objects' value being looped for the properties' value.
I got the value and wanted to pass it into an element's attribute BUT there's already value in the attribute and I want the properties' value from object to be a part of the attribute value.

let's take the youtube videoID for example

in javascript, here stores the videoId for youtube

```
request.execute(function(response){
    var results = response.result;
    $.each(results.items, function(index, item){
        var videoId = item.id.videoId;
    });
});
```

in html using the iframe

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

above, we can see if the `videoId` from the js is plugged into the `VIDEOID` in the html then the video will be shown on the html page.

How can I pass the `videoId` value into the `VIDEOID` by using plain javascript/jQuery?

Comment: `this.src = this.src + 'VIDEOID'`, but you should probably be more specific, do you only want to add this once, never remove etc. and do the URL's always end with `/`, there's many problems here that **can** run into

Comment: I am actually playing with the youtube api, have a search to search for the videos and output with max let's say 3 outputs.  I know there are other options but somehow this just popped up in my head

Answer (score 1):

set an id for your iframe like so

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="" frameborder="0" id = "yt_iframe" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and add this to your jQuery

```
$("#yt_iframe").attr("src", "http://youtube.com/embed/" + videoId)
```

i haven't tried this, but it should.

Comment: this would work only if there's one iframe isn't it? If let's say the result ends up in 5 videos, would this still work?

Comment: @Dora - if you have five iframes with the same ID, you have other issues.

Comment: @adeneo that's what I am thinking but my head isn't getting around

Comment: what do you mean ?. the code would work only for the iframe that has the same id. if you want to play 5 video on a single iframe one after another, then thats another logic.

or if you want to play 5 videos at the same time you can save those videoId as an array, get it's length and create a loop from the length where each loop would generate an iframe with an attached videoId[x] on it.

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose, i have Iframes with attribute called VideoID in all with some value in it.

Now I want to put that value of VideoID appended to the src, i would use below approach.

```
//Looping through all the iframes    
$("iframe").each(function(){

   //appending the value if video ID to the SRC    
   $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src')+$(this).attr('VideoID'));

});
```

Hope this will help.